# How to express informal strong dislike

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, antonyms

As you can say in a positive informal way that you have a "soft spot" for something, or you "have a thing for"... what would you use to say informally you have a dislike or you do not tolerate something/someone (or a category of thing/people)?

For example, we talk about the kind of people we like or not, so I'd say that I have a soft spot for genuine people but I _____ dishonest people

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I understand why you want a synonym for "dislike", but did you put it into a thesaurus? Did the results answer your question? If not, then why not?

Comment: You can say:- **you have a hard spot for dishonest people.**

Comment: @Sam - I have never heard anyone say that, and it could be easily misinterpreted.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it's informal...

Comment: @Sam Micheal is right. That isn't idiomatic, and if you think about it, it could be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some:
"I can't stand dishonest people."
"I have zero tolerance for liars."
"I don't like dishonest people"

Answer (score 0):

@Big Mistake's answers are fine, but they are quite emphatic. That's fine if you want to say something unambiguous like you *do not tolerate* something.

A phrase like "I have a soft spot for" is quite non-emphatic, on the other hand. It is expressing a significant liking, but not a strong or overpowering one.

So if you wanted something equally non-emphatic with a negative sense you could say:

> I'm not a fan of ...

> I don't particularly like ...

#### Side note on "softening idioms" for expressing negative opinions (especially about people):

Confusingly for learners, phrases like the ones above can on the surface appear to indicate that someone *does* like something a certain amount. "I don't particularly like", if taken literally, actually means "I do like, but not in a notable way". But it would be understood to mean the person was at best neutral about the thing, and probably disliked it. Moreover,  if somebody said:

> I like Mary, but I'm not a big fan of John.

It would usually be understood to mean that the speaker was not a fan of John *at all*.

English speakers often soften phrases expressing strong opinions with qualifiers, and by reversing the sense of the sentence to avoid a direct statement with a negative meaning.

> John is fat.

The above sentence is a very bold statement in normal or polite conversation, and in most contexts would be interpreted as rude.

> John is not exactly slim.

This sentence reverses the sense of the first sentence as a way to indirectly say something about a person's weight. It would usually be understood clearly to indicate that John *is* overweight. But the phrasing softens the implication enough to probably avoid appearing rude ... at least if said in an appropriate context. (Obviously such statements about a person, even when made indirectly in this way, can still be highly inappropriate in many contexts).

Answer (score 0):

To have a soft spot generally means you feel more fondness or tenderness towards something compared to the general population, like having a soft spot for cyclists or travellers or stray dogs.

In that same sense, to express *dislike for something more than the average person*, here are a couple terms and expressions:

---

**have a thing about X**

While "to have a thing *for* X" means to have more *positive* feelings about X than normal, "to have a thing *about* X" means to have more *negative* feelings about X than normal:

> I have a thing about people leaving dishes in the sink.

---

**[bugaboo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bugaboo)**

> something that causes fear or distress out of proportion to its importance

"Bugaboo" with this meaning is nearly always used with "have", as in:

> I have a bugaboo about hard candy.